# How to show a Toast like alert, that run globally without attaching to any Activity Context showing above all activities?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toast, android-background

I am developing an Android app.

In that, the existing flow is, there is a  Toast Broadcasting Class which listened by MainActivity

Now we will call the emitter for the Toast from any activity and the toast will be shown from MainActivity (which is in onPaused state but alive , backstacked )

For example, We will call the emitter from WebViewActivity, the toast listener called from MainActivity will show the toast

Note that the Toast is an custom toast where the custom layout binded by toast.setView(layout)

Now my problem is ,

Starting from Android 11+,

If I call the toast emitter from MainActivity itself , that is when MainActivity is on top and Resumed , it's successfully shown

But, If I call it from Other Activites when MainActivity is passed, toast not showing

(I am using getApplicationContext to provide context for the toast)

I searched in the internet and found out that Custom Layout toast are deprecated after API LEVEL 30 and Toast cannot called from background

So is there is any way to show a Toast like alert, that run globally without attaching to any Activity Context showing above all activities  ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct. I suggest you create a `BaseActivity` class and extend all your activities from it. And move your Toast logic from `MainActivity` to `BaseActivity`. Now you can use your Toast in your current active activity.

Comment: Thanks. Tried that. Still problem persist.

Comment: @RagAnt what do you mean? It's impossible because in this case you just use it like a regular Toast without all your useless "workarounds". Just remove your overhead and do it as normal people do;)